# Not able to make a simple proof in Dafny: if `0<=a<=1 & 0<=b<=1 & -1<=c<=1` then `a*b*c==1 ==> a=1 & b=1 & c=1`

Tags: z3, proof, theorem-proving, dafny

I am not able to prove a simple property: if `0<=a<=1 & 0<=b<=1 & -1<=c<=1` then `a*b*c==1 ==> a=1 & b=1 & c=1`.

I first tested the following:

```
lemma threepowers(a:real,b:real,c:real)
   requires 0.0<=a<=1.0 && 0.0<=b<=1.0 && -1.0<=c<=1.0
   ensures a*b*c==1.0 ==> a==1.0 && b==1.0 && c==1.0
   {
     if (a<1.0 || b<1.0 || c<1.0){
       assert a*b*c < 1.0;
     }
   }
```

But the assertion fails.

So I decided to prove it by cases, as follows (note that I only show a couple of cases):

```
lemma threepowers(a:real,b:real,c:real)
   requires 0.0<=a<=1.0 && 0.0<=b<=1.0 && -1.0<=c<=1.0
   ensures a*b*c==1.0 ==> a==1.0 && b==1.0 && c==1.0
   {
     if (a==1.0){
       if ((b == 1.0 && c!=1.0)||(b != 1.0 && c==1.0)){
         assert a*b*c!=1.0;
       }
       else if (b != 1.0 && c!=1.0){
         assert a*b*c!=1.0;
       }
     }
     
     
   }
```

But Dafny is not able to verify that if `b` and `c` are both not `1` (i.e., they are smaller than `1`, taking into account the `requires`), then the product `a*b*c` is not `1`.

What basic issue am I missing?

Of course, note that a Z3 call is not able to prove it either:

```
lemma threepowers(a:real,b:real,c:real)
   requires 0.0<=a<=1.0 && 0.0<=b<=1.0 && -1.0<=c<=1.0
   ensures a*b*c==1.0 ==> a==1.0 && b==1.0 && c==1.0
   {
     assert forall x:real :: forall y:real :: forall z:real :: (0.0<=x<1.0) || (0.0<=y<1.0) || (-1.0<=z<1.0) ==> (x*y*z<1.0);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a two-line proof for a variant of your problem

```
lemma threepowers(a:real,b:real,c:real)
   requires 0.0<=a<=1.0 && 0.0<=b<=1.0 && -1.0<=c<=1.0
   ensures a*b*c==1.0 ==> a==1.0 && b==1.0 && c==1.0
   {
     if a*b*c == 1.0 && a < 1.0 && b < 1.0 && b != 0.0 && c != 0.0 {
     }
   }
```

but because I find the process more interesting that the solution, here is the methodology I followed.

1. I first started by trying to prove a lemma with only two reals instead of three.

```
lemma twopowers(a: real, b: real)
  requires 0.0<=a<=1.0 && 0.0<=b<=1.0
  ensures a*b==1.0 ==> a==1.0 && b==1.0
{
}
```

That did not work either. So I started to follow verification debugging techniques and inserted

```
  if a*b == 1.0 {             // Just added
    assert a==1.0 && b==1.0;  // Just added
  }                           // Just added
```

but that did not work yet. My next move was to think. Well, if it cannot prove that a == 1.0, I can assume that a != 1.0 and perhaps obtain a proof by contradiction. So my proof changed to

```
  if a*b == 1.0 {
    if a != 1.0 {    // Just added
      assert false;  // Just added
    }                // Just added
    assert a==1.0 && b==1.0;
  }
```

And curiously, it conditionally proved the two assertions `a==1.0` and `b==1.0`
So now, how do I prove there is a contradiction?
Well, the only thing I could try was to derive more facts. Since a is not 1, it has to be strictly less than 1, so I asserted it.

```
  if a*b == 1.0 {
    if a != 1.0 {
      assert a < 1.0; // Just added
      assert false;   // Still not verifying
    }
    assert a==1.0 && b==1.0;
  }
```

Then, since I knew that `a*b == 1.0`, I thought I would be able to derive that `a*b < 1.0 * b`. but it turned out, this is not true.

```
  if a*b == 1.0 {
    if a != 1.0 {
      assert a < 1.0; 
      assert a*b < 1.0*b; // Does not verify
      assert false;       // OK now
    }
    assert a==1.0 && b==1.0;
  }
```

The reason is obvious. If b is zero, there should be an equality. So, I needed the case split `b != 0` And suddenly, the entire function verified.

```
  if a*b == 1.0 {
    if a != 1.0 {
      assert a < 1.0;
      if b != 0.0 {
        assert a*b < 1.0*b;
      } else {
        assert a*b == 1.0*b;
      }
      assert false;
    }
    assert a==1.0 && b==1.0;
  }
```

Dafny figured out that, in one case `a*b < 1.0*b <= b <= 1`, so `a*b < 1` and we had a contradiction.
In the other case, `a*b == 0` so `0 == 1` and that's another contradiction.

So I tried a similar strategy for your lemma, it was a bit longer, but I found the solution above by trial and error.
I first changed the interval of `c` to `0.0<=c<=1.0`, and then supposed that `a*b*c == 1`. Then I tried `a < 1.0`, then `b < 1.0` and then what if `b != 0` and `c != 0`, and it arrived not only at a contradiction in this case, but it was enough for the verifier to figure out all the other cases.
I then simplified the nested if-else structure until I kept the minimum of the proof, and voilà !

Then, to make it easier to reproduce, I did another experiment. I created the skeleton of a proof:

```
  if a*b*c == 1.0 {
    if a < 1.0 || b < 1.0 || c < 1.0 {
      if a < 1.0 {
        assert false;
      } else if b < 1.0 {
        assert false;
      } else {
        assert c < 1.0;
        assert false;
      }
    }
    assert a==1.0 && b==1.0 && c==1.0;
  }
```

Only the two first assert were failing. I focused on the first. I added the split `if a != 0.0` with an `assert false` in its body, and only the first branch was failing.

Similarly, I added the split `if b != 0.0` with `assert false` in its body, and only the first branch was failing.

Then I added the triple split `if c < 0.0 { assert false; } else if c == 0.0 { assert false; } else { assert c > 0.0; assert false; }`
And only the third assert was failing.

Then, in this branch, I added assertions to prove manually the contradiction:

```
assert c*b > 0.0;
assert a*(b*c) < 1.0*(b*c);
assert c*b <= 1.0; // Failing
```

I added two new assertions in front of the failing assert:

```
assert b <= 1.0;
assert b*c <= 1.0 * b;
```

And the second one did the trick.
Then, all my job was to simplify the proof. I removed all the `else { assert false; }` for example. I removed the wrapper `if a < 1.0 || b < 1.0 || c < 1.0 {` since proving it on one case make it possible to prove it for all cases. I collapsed the tower of ifs, and my proof became the simple

```
  if a*b*c == 1.0 && a < 1.0 && a != 0.0 && b != 0.0 && c > 0.0 {
    assert b*c <= 1.0 * b;
  }
```

From here one would be very happy to have a proof, but I did one more step: I put the assertion in the condition:

```
  if a*b*c == 1.0 && a < 1.0 && a != 0.0 && b != 0.0 && c > 0.0 && b*c <= 1.0 * b {
  }
```

and that worked! I was even able to remove `c > 0.0` and `a*b*c == 1.0` and here is the shortest proof I could find:

```
  if a < 1.0 && a != 0.0 && b != 0.0 && b*c <= 1.0 * b {}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the great response! I really though the problem was much easier, sorry for making you do all this!! Sometimes it gets hard to know how Dafny elucidates and derives knowledge. What I receive from this response is that I should first split the problem into a more simple one to see if Dafny still gets in trouble with the simplified version. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: What I still do not perfectly understand is the following, let me try to explain it. When we write the definitive `if a < 1.0 && a != 0.0 && b != 0.0 && b*c <= 1.0 * b {}` statement in the Lemma, what does this internally mean? Does this mean that Dafny is already able to prove the whole `!(if a < 1.0 && a != 0.0 ...`? Then, how is Dafny able to prove this statement's truth with no assertions? I mean, which is the internal difference between explicitly indicating `(if a < 1.0 && a != 0.0...` it and not doing it? Does not Dafny have a "verification region finder", to say so?

Comment: Internally, a call `if A && B && C { } assert X` is translated to boogie like `if A { if B { If C { assert X } else { assert X } } else { assert X } } else { assert X } }`, because it will compute all the possible paths that lead to the assertion `assert X` and ensure it's valid on every path. Similarly, if you had `if A {} if B {} if C{} assert X`, it will consider all the possible 8 paths to prove X, if I'm not mistaken.
Since a post-condition is an implicit assert after this if, that's why you don't need to specify it inside the lemma. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! In other lemmas out there, I have also seen the usage of keyword `return` inside each branch (say `if b==0 {return;}`). Is this equivalent to using the implicit `assert` of the `ensures`? Then, why use it?

Comment: Yes it's equivalent to that and then assuming false, from a verification's perspective.
But for an execution's perspective, you still want the keyword "return"

Comment: Hmm... you mean that 'return' is necessary if we are to execute the file?

Comment: What I mean is that, from verification's perspective, `ensures E { if b == 0 {X; return; } A }` is equivalent to `ensures E { if b == 0 { X; assert E; assume false} A`, which is equivalent to `(b != 0 || ([whatever X encodes] && E) && (b == 0 || (whatever A encodes) && E)`. However, assume statements are not compilable. It's just an intermediate language before full logic